# Find existing JWT token for user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I've got a function to manually create a new `AccessToken` for a user (using the `rest_framework_simplejwt` library):

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken

def create_access_token_for_user(user):
    access_token = AccessToken.for_user(user)
```

Now I'm trying to write a test to verify that this is actually working as expected, and I can't seem to find any way of getting the `AccessToken` for a given user. The test should look something like:

```
def test_access_token_created(client):
    user = create_user()
    create_access_token_for_user(user)

    access_token = AccessToken.get_token_for_user(user)  # This, but real

    assert access_token is not None  # Or some check to see if it exists
```

The [rest_framework_simplejwt docs](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest_framework_simplejwt.html) don't seem to have anything that does this, or at least nothing that I've been able to use correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact implementation behind the library, but usually JWT is stateless, which means that it isn't stored anywhere in your server (not in your database), so don't think of the AccessToken as a Model you could query on to find the related user or which token was generated for which user.

Also, it's usually unnecessary to test an external library, at least if it's popular. You can refer to the tests written by the developers, available in the official repository.

Comment: Yup, thanks for clarifying that. New to JWT tokens and still wrapping my head around it all.

Oh, and the tests are integration tests to make sure the entire API endpoint works as expected.